# How to trigger an event after transition stopped in javafx 2.4.0?

Tags: java, animation, javafx-2

My [PathTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/PathTransition.html) animates a a few labels and have an [setOnFinished](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#setOnFinished(javafx.event.EventHandler))-event. When a label is entered with the cursor this label animates and stop the animation of the previous label if there is one.

```
Label l1 = new Label("Hello");
Label l2 = new Label("Hello");

Path path = new Path();
path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(100,100);
path.getElements().add(new LineTo(200,200));

PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(1000));
pathTransition.setPath(path);
pathTransition.setNode(l1);
pathTransition.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        // do something
    }
});

pathTransition.play()

// if i enter l2 i want stop the l1 animation
pathTransition.stop()

// animate the l2
// ...
```

My Problem is that pathTransition.stop() stops the animation but the onFinished-event doesn't trigger. Is there any solution to trigger an event after the pathTransition stopped?

I hope my question is understandable.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for changes made to the animation's `statusProperty`:

```
pathTransition.statusProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Status>() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Status> observableValue,
                        Status oldValue, Status newValue) {
          if(newValue==Status.STOPPED){
                //do something
          }            
    }
});
```